# I can't compile a GTA V script on C#. The type of namespace Player cannot be found

Tags: c#, scripting

I am using rage multiplayer server that runs on C# scripts. It makes it possible for gta v to play on a server with custom game modes.

The problem is this:
The type or namespace name 'Player' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLRFF6A36mM

the code is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using GTANetworkAPI;
 
namespace gtavrp.Commands
{
    class PlayerCommands : Script
    {
        //~o~ stands for orange ~w~ stands for white
        //Below that is the description
        [Command("me", "~o~Usage: ~w~ /me [action]", GreedyArg = true)]
        public void CMD_Me(Player player, string action)
        {
            //This removes the extra spaces inside the chat
            action = action.Trim();
 
            List<Player> nearbyPlayers = NAPI.Player.GetPlayersInRadiusOfPlayer(20, player);
 

            foreach (Player item in nearbyPlayers)
            {
                item.SendChatMessage($"~p~{player.Name} {action}");
            }
 
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried adding this line of code:

using GTANetworkMethods;

but it still didn't repair the problem, because I have ended up having a problem with the item.SendChatMessage, even though it did stop marking the Player as an error

I did replace the Player with Client, and still no success, the script does not load when the server runs if it is replaced with the Client instead of Player.

Please do help, I don't know how to fix this problem

Comment: You'll probably need that using statement, and it sounds like it will fix this problem but you have the separate problem with item.SendChatMessage. Do you have any details on that issue?

Comment: ok, so now I'm stuck with the SendChatMessage and Player.Name, if I'm going to use the code : 
using GTANetworkMethods;

Comment: You need to tell us the new error message you're getting for item.SendChatMessage.

Comment: The new error on SendChatMessage and player.Name is : CS1061: 'Player' does not contain a definition for 'SendChatMessage' and no accessible extension method ' SendChatMessage ' accepting a first argument of type 'Player' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: https://wiki.gtanet.work/index.php?title=Client suggests that `Player` should indeed be `Client`. What exactly goes wrong when you replace `Player` with `Client`?

Comment: I already did that. When I swap the Client with the Player, this error is what I get inside the server:
https://imgur.com/T2hvxzN

Comment: Here is the solution:
https://rage.mp/forums/topic/10221-helpi-cant-compile-the-script-the-type-or-namespace-name-player-could-not-be-found/